# Android How to mock Application?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, powermock

I write `androidTest` for class that using `SharedPreferences`. Constructor of the class contains this code:

```
    public PreferencesReader() {  
        sharedPrefs =  MyApplication.getContext().getSharedPreferences(name, mode);  
}
```

I need to test the constructor, but I have an error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference` because of cannot mock static method `getContext()` and `Application` class.

I've read a lot of pages, tried `Powermock`, that compiles with errors and so on.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there any way to easy mocking `Application` or stub static method without `Powermock`?
2. Is there any working sample project with such stuff that is up-to-date for current `Mockito`, `Powermock` and `JUnit4` versions?

Thank you!